# Edittext change line color and text color different

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design

i am using AppCompatEditText my layout is

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.app.dream11.UI.CustomEditTextView
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter your name"
        CustomEditTextView:fontType="Xanadu" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

in style i have define as

```
<style name="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.TextFloatLabelAppearance</item>
    <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.TextErrorAppearance</item>
    <item name="counterTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Counter</item>
    <item name="counterOverflowTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Counter.Overflow
    </item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.TextFloatLabelAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <!-- Floating label appearance here -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/warm_grey_two</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.TextErrorAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Error">
    <!-- Error message appearance here -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/pale_red</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/denim_blue</item>


</style>
```

```
    <!-- edittext line color -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white_four</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/greyish_brown</item>
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/App_EditTextStyle</item> <!-- For compatibility with the support library -->

</style>
```

but now problem is when i set line color of edittext say blue then text color also become blue but i want 
   line color should be different and text color also different

Answer (score 0):

**have a look on this color primary and colorAccent these are used the color change of edit text line on focus and focus do change on it**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item> //this color change your line color of edittext
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
   //text color of edittext
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white_four</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/greyish_brown</item>

</style>
```

Comment: so in my case i have different color for primary

Comment: use this on main theme....... and change the colors as you want on line on change of colorprimary and coloraccent

Answer (score 0):

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="EditTextCustom" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_light</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

**XML code:**

```
<EditText
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   style="@style/EditTextCustom"/>
```

Comment: @andro have you try this?